# Inverse Laplace of a transfer function for $\frac{K_{s}.P_{0}}{s.(s.T_{1}+1)} + \frac{V_{a}}{s}$

Tags: inverse-laplace

I have the following function in the Laplace domain:
$$\frac{K_{s}.P_{0}}{s.(s.T_{1}+1)} + \frac{V_{a}}{s}$$

And I want to do the inverse Laplace transform.So, this is my result:
$$L^{-1} (V(s))=K_s.P_0.(1-  e^{(-t/T_1)})+ v_a$$

Could anyone check the correctness of my work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer looks correct. You can check that using [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20laplace%20transform%20%28K*P%29%2F%28s%28T*s%2B1%29%29%20%2B%20V%2Fs). We need only use partial fraction decomposition and $\mathcal{L}[t^n] = \frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$. Let me know if I can help.